# How would I add javascript to a page override chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am using this (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) method to create a new tab replacement page for a chrome extension. I want to add javascript that can change the HTML DOM (a clock in this case). I know how to make the clock but was wondering what I have to put in manifest.json to allow this js file. Thanks!

Comment: There's a link to demo extensions in the documentation. There's also an example of what you should write in manifest.json. Not sure what's the problem here.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would need to use the `<script type="text/javascript" src="override.js"></script>` tag in your case.